# SSIS package import from file error handling

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to run a very simple SSIS package where I am dumping the contents of an Excel file into a database. The job is scheduled, but the file it is reading from is manually moved to the source location.

As it stands, if no one puts the Excel file in the staging area before the package runs the whole process fails.

Is there a way to not kill the job if the import file is missing? Maybe just log an error and try again later?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of ways.  You just want the job to go to the next step even if the step that executes the package fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to handle this is use a ForEach enumator and set a variable to the count of files in the folder.  If the count is 0, gracefully exit out of the ForEach and set the precedence constraint accordingly.